# present collection view controller from a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

for some reason my code prints out the `user.email` fine but it doesn't present the chatlog controller for the user, it just does nothing?

(the `func openUsersChatLogForUser()` is called when i clicked on a button with in the header)

with in - `class ProfilePageHeader: UICollectionViewCell`

```
var messagesController: MessagesController?

func openUsersChatLogForUser(){

    guard let user = self.profileUser else {return}

    print(user.email!)

    self.messagesController?.showChatControllerForUser(user)
}
```

---

the function below is within the class `MessagesController: UITableViewController`

```
func showChatControllerForUser(_ user: User2) {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if `messagesController` contains value (not nil).

2) Check if there is `navigationController` that manages `MessagesController`. If it is not there, embed that controller into `UINavigationController`. Otherwise it won't be able to push anything.

3) Unlikely, but still can be: call `showChatControllerForUser`  from main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.messagesController?.showChatControllerForUser(user)
}
```

Comment: thanks Hexfire messageController is equal to nil how would i set it?

Comment: Just set its value upon populating collection view with your custom cells.

Comment: It's `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` method that you are looking for. When calling `collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` you cast it to your custom cell. then call: `cell.messagesController` = ...  controller.

Comment: i placed messageController = MessagesController() in the didSet though now i get an error 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
*** First throw call stack:
(

Comment: this is wrong. You should refer existing instance of MessagesController, not the new one. Is it the controller that owns collectionview? If yes, then just assign `self`.

Comment: thanks i put self.messagesController = MessagesController() in didSet and then i still get the error  'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: also the button is being pressed inside the header and header doesn't have cell for item

Comment: Do you have any success?

Comment: I didn't sorry .